# Django - Correct way to load a large default value in a model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a field called `schema` in a django model that usually contains a rather large json string. There is a default value (around 2000 characters) that I would like added when any new instance is created.

I find it rather unclean to dump the whole thing in the `models.py` in a variable. What is the best way to load this default value in my schema (which is a `TextField`)?

Example:

```
class LevelSchema(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(to=User)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    schema = models.TextField() # Need a default value for this
```

I thought about this a bit. If I am using a json file to store the default value somewhere, what is the best place to put it? Obviously it is preferable if it is in the same app in a folder.

Comment: What's so unclean about putting it in a variable?

Comment: The text is rather massive. Would span half the file as it is formatted json which I would like editable in future. I prefer loading it from a file (like fixtures), just that I want to know if there is a method already present in Django.

Comment: In this case it is just about the json, which is still bearable as it looks like a Python dict, what if there was some other kind of large piece of text, say XML/HTML? Not to mention a multiple lines (in 100s).

Comment: I don't think there is anything provided by Django for this kind of job. If you like to not have it in your models module, perhaps create a `data` directory, put the json file there and read it when needed? You can find its path as path relative to your models module. Other option would be to put this in fixtures, but this is not a valid fixture so I think `data` or something like that would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The text is rather massive. Would span half the file as it is
>   formatted json which I would like editable in future. I prefer loading
>   it from a file (like fixtures), just that I want to know if there is a
>   method already present in Django.

In django, you have two options:

1. Listen on [post_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-save), and when `created` is true, set the default value of the object by reading the file.
2. Set the default to a callable (a function), and in that method read the file (make sure you close it after), and return its contents.

You can also stick the data in some k/v store (like redis or memcache) for faster access. It would also be better since you won't be constantly opening and closing files.

Finally, the most restrictive option would be to set up a trigger on the database that does the populating for you. You would have to store the json in the database somewhere. Added benefit to this approach is that you can write a django front end to update the json. Downside is it will restrict your application to those database that you decide to support with your trigger.

Answer (score 1):

I find the use of a variable not particularly unclean. But you could "abuse" the
fact that the `default` argument, that all fields support, can be a callable.

So you could this "crazy" thing:

```
def get_default_json():
    json_text = open('mylargevalue.json').read()
    return json_text
```

and then on your field:

```
schema = models.TextField(default=get_default_json)
```

I haven't tried anything like it, but I suppose it could work.